# How can I print out html tag specifying where using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to print html tag in php where ever you want?
For example I want to print table right after button where $dataName equals to specific name.

I am coding data update page for html page using php in body field, AJAX for getting data from other SQL query coding PHP script.

In the for()coding in html page,using php in body field, I have button(buttons, multiple cuz I have them on loop) and table(also multiple) which will show new data from database.
I have a problem showing new data in a specific place where I want to show write after specific button.
Because I have them on loop, when I click the button, I get new data(same) to each multiple button and this is the problem.

↓This is what I want to show after clicking button 
Old data for A
Button A
(New data for A)
Old data for B
Button B
(New data for B)
Old data for C
Button C 
(New data for C)

↓This is what I get after clicking button A
Old data for A
Button A
(New data for A) 
Old data for B
Button B
(New data for A)
Old data for C
Button C 
(New data for A)

```
//button written in body field in the middle of php coding<br>
print"<button class='refresh' data-name='$dataName'>{$dataName} DATA UPDATE</button>";<br>

//data shows up when button is clicked<br>
print "<table class='show' id='$dataName'></table>";<br>
```

Comment: First include your <br> tag in your string, else you gona have syntax error

Comment: Like that : print "<table class='show' id='$dataName'></table><br>";

Comment: Thank you for the comment ! but it won't solve for the question.

Comment: Keep in mind that 100% of php will get executed before your frontend code is run. So you cannot have a JavaScript condition that invokes php without a separate web request